# Geometric probability in R with 2 variables

Tags: r

Here I have written a code that uses the geometrical function rgeom() to check if something was successful on the first try. However, I can't get it to say how many times it took, when it has to be successful on the first try. 
Thats the reason i assign A & B to get its values from k. When k has been reached, it was supposed to print out how many times it took, but now it only prints out k+1.

```
test <- function(k){
p <- 1/3
trials <- 1
A <- k
B <- k
for(i in 1:1000){
  while(B > 0){
   if (rgeom(1, p) == 0){
     B = B-1
     trials = trials +1
     break
   }else {
     A = A-1
     break
   }
  }
}
print(trials)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
p <- 1/3 # parameter of the geometric variable
n <- 1000 # number of trials
sum(replicate(n, {rgeom(1,p)})==1) # number of times it was successful on the first try
```

Comment: You did help me solve the task :) I ended up solving it like this.  
test <- function(k){
p <- 2/3
trials <- 0
A <- k
B <- k
for(i in 1:100){
    a <- replicate(1, {rgeom(1, p)})==0
    b <- replicate(1, {rgeom(1, p)})==0
      if(a==FALSE){
      A <- A-1
      trials <- trials +1
      i <- i-1
      if(A == 0){
        print(trials)
        stop("A = 0")
      }
    }
    if(b==FALSE){
      B <- B-1
      trials <- trials +1
      i <- i-1
      if(B== 0){
        print(trials)
        stop("B = 0")
      }
    }
}
print(A)
print(B)
print(trials)
}

Comment: You don't get much formatting capability in comments. If you think you have a better answer, you just add it in an answer editing box with full formatting.